# Offline data storage in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, offline-caching

Just wanted to know is there any way where we can store offline data/imagee(20MB+) in HTML which is supported IE 10 metro browser. I haver gone through below links

[Building Offline storage](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/09/27/building-offline-experiences-with-html5-appcache-and-indexeddb.aspx)

Appreciate you can give me a running sample which stores the data/images locally and retrieves later on. Note this should be supported on IE10 of Windows 8 metro(tablet PC).

Comment: I think http://html5demos.com/ can help you. I am not familiar with Windows 8 metro myself, so I can't say what futures are fully available on it. The site linked allows you to see short examples from futures and the source used to create that example.

Comment: Hi, you might need to be a bit more specific with your problem in order to get a useful response. You say you went through that article. What issues did you have with the code there?

Comment: That doesn't have a working code. Any running sample on Windows 8 metrow IE 10 browser would be helpful

Comment: @Sumurai8 I think this is link is not helping me. It has some offline mecahnism which is not supported in IE>

Comment: There are quite a lot of options for you to try but the problem is that you need to store 20MB+ data which is not allowed in any browser by default.

Comment: @sv_in can you suggest any working sample please. Let's first see working sample we can think about size later on

Answer (score 0):

There are several means of doing this:

- Using the [appCache](http://appcachefacts.info/), you can store offline data using manifests, but are you are strictly limited in how much data you can store
- Using the [indexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB), you can store much more data, but it's up to you to read and write the data programatically.

using a combination of the two, you can use the appCache to store your HTML/JavaScript offline, and then, while offline, pull the 20+MB of image data out of the indexedDB.

Comment: This is great..can you give me any working sample or link which may help me..thanks for your help here

Comment: As meagar said, you have to do some reading. HTML5 is something new. Not all of the features are supported by all the browsers.